# Read-Only ToggleButton or CheckBox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, checkbox, togglebutton

By default, WPF ToggleButton or CheckBox (which inherits ToggleButton) doesn't have some kind of ReadOnly property to prevent user from changing the value.

One technic consists in setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `Focusable="False"`.

I thought that I could also achieve this binding the `IsChecked` property to a `get` only accessor.

#### Bound model

```cs
class SomeViewModel
{
  public bool Checked => true;
}
```

#### View

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=OneWay}">
```

But unfortunately, this is not working, the user can still change the CheckBox value...

Comment: You missed the IsEnabled property.

Comment: I know IsEnabled property, but it affects the style by graying it out, this is not what I want.

Comment: But that visualization is the common way to let the user of your application know that they can not interact with the control. A disabled CheckBox that looks enabled is annoying.

Comment: @Clemens this is not the question here. Deciding wether it is good or bad is subjective. In my case, all my UI is read only and this is perfectly assumed.
Additionally we might want to display a message if the user click whereas some conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: I would consider re templating completely to show something doesn't look exactly like a checkbox - maybe a green tick / red cross. Then set is enabled false.

Comment: I think setting IsHitTestVisible="False" will suffice. It won't change the appearance.

Comment: @emoacht no it will not suffice, because CheckBox can still be checked using tab key and space key.

Comment: @Kino101 I see. You didn't mentioned it.

Comment: @emoacht it is in the question: ReadOnly property to **prevent user from changing the value**

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Based on the comments you don't want a "read-only" control (you don't read from a control) but you want to disable it for user interactions. But you still want to be able to change the value of a particular property programmatically or via data binding, animation etc. Is that correct? Then why is the `IsHitTestVisible` feature not a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case unfortunately, the binding is getting out of synchronization when user changes the value.

Below a solution which consists in always refreshing the binding when the user changes the value.

#### ToggleButtonEx class

```cs
public static class ToggleButtonEx
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleButtonEx), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is not ToggleButton toggleButton)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"This property may only be set on {nameof(ToggleButton)}.");

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            toggleButton.Checked += OnCheckChanged;
            toggleButton.Unchecked += OnCheckChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            toggleButton.Checked -= OnCheckChanged;
            toggleButton.Unchecked -= OnCheckChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnCheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = ((ToggleButton)sender).GetBindingExpression(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty);
        binding?.UpdateTarget();
    }

    public static void SetIsReadOnly(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsReadOnly(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty);
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```xml
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=OneWay}" ns:ToggleButtonEx.IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: I think it's getting downvoted since this deviates from typical MVVM approaches with WPF, which are generally preferred and accepted as best practice. In MVVM, we try to avoid manipulating the View's elements with events and triggers in the code behind as you have laid out. The preferred approach is to leverage the ViewModel and its properties to control the View.

Comment: On the contrary @egeer, it perfectly respects the MVVM pattern as this solution is a only UI behavior expectation. The ViewModel from the original question (SomeViewModel) shouldn't do more than what it does.
There is no contradiction in expecting a ReadOnly propery on a CheckBox. Moreover note that `TextBox` has a `IsReadOnly` property ;)

Comment: This is a totally weird solution. The user can interact with the control (mouse over effects, clickable, keyboard navigable) but his actions will have no effect (like if the GUI hangs or has crashed).  And it doesn't perform well because it allows potential animations and triggers to execute before you forcefully revert the value. However, this solution allows a ToggleButton to attach but then handles the more specialized CheckBox. The explicit cast in the event handler will then crash the application unexpectedly. A type that implements attached properties should also extend DependencyObject.

Comment: @BionicCode cast fixed: initially I was working on CheckBox until I notice CheckBox inherits ToggleButton.
Why writing with so much arrogance ? Can't you simply say that there is a cast issue ?
Additionnally, **no it is not mandatory for a class  to derive from DependencyObject** [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/attached-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0#how-to-create-an-attached-property).
To quote you "like if the GUI hangs or has crashed": this is subjective, read comments in question.

Comment: What was arrogant here? I think I was very technically focused. *"no it is not mandatory for a class to derive from DependencyObject"* - I never said anything like that. I said *should*. That's a big difference opposed to*mandatory*. You brought up that word. *"this is subjective"* - While it is a subjective experience, we can say that this is the common perception based on GUI behavior that is the standard in every professional application. And this behavior is standard for a good reason.

Comment: Hover effects are not fancy candy. They serve the only purpose to provide the user cues on what he can do and what not. These are UI design basics. If objects act like they are for interaction but interacting with them doesn't yield results everybody will think something is wrong. I just gave you feedback and suggestions. If you believe this is good UI design I really don't bother.

Comment: I agree the difference between should and mandatory, it was simply inappropriate to mention that it should inherit DependencyObject as it is not required in this context. For me, it was more sounding like you were trying to find any argument to discredit this article.
I also agree you about "UI design basics", I never said this solution is good, but I really think this article may help some people in some rare contexts (even for educational purpose only).

Comment: Finally, the problem I point here is more semantic. Having a IsReadOnly property **(once again like TextBox have)** would be more comprehensible, comforting and intuitive than setting IsHitTestVisible and Focusable to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what I believe you want:

**Model**

```
class SomeViewModel
{
  public bool Checked 
  {
      get => true;
      set {}
  }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False"
          IsChecked="{Binding Checked}">
```

Leaving the binding as two-way causes WPF to fetch the updated value from the getter - which in this case is always true - after the button is pressed and the source property is updated, overriding the default behavior which would be just to toggle it.

I agree with some of the comments that some kind of visual indication is preferable - or perhaps more accurately, the absence of visual feedback (e.g. the button shouldn't light up on hover). `IsHitTestVisible=false` would help with this, but of course it's up to you.